# about equivalent expressions showing the remaining time to a point

Tags: time

In this question, I would like to ask you different ways of expressing time remaining to a specific point, particularly using an example which is a line from a TV drama. And there are several alternative patterns to the example sentence I am not sure are correct.

The example sentence below is a line said by an anchor on a radio news in the thrilling drama, **The Purge** from Amazon Prime Video. The purge in the drama means a night in a year that all crimes including murder are allowed for several hours until the morning.

> Original Line: We are just minutes away from the start of this glorious holiday.

I am wondering about other equivalent expressions to it.
For that, I've made up several expressions using different patterns below. I would greatly appreciate it if you answer which is right and wrong and why it is. Any additional explanations would be very helpful.

> **A**. We only have minutes until/before the start of this glorious holiday.
>
> **B**. There are only minutes left until/before the start of this glorious holiday.
>
> **C**. It is only minutes until/before the start of this glorious holiday.

Thank you.

Comment: All of your variants are idiomatic. But **before** and **until** can mean different things. Here, the reference is to the time remaining, so they mean the same. They introduce the event that marks the end of the wait.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for the neat answer as always. I am not doubting your answer, but is the sentence **C** really correct? Actually, **C** is the one I was the most unsure of. :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo When hearing **C** being said, it sounds okay but when seeing it grammatically, it somehow feels weird to me. Maybe it is because of the use of **it** there, which is a pronoun that doesn't seem to have any explicit reference in meaning.

Comment: For **It is only minutes until..** see the examples to be found among the items here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22only%20minutes%20until%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: For **It is only minutes before...** see the examples to be found among the items here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20only%20minutes%20before%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for the examples and helps, sir. I appreciate it. Have a lovely day.

Comment: You are welcome. **There are...** and **It is ...** are both idiomatic forms of "existential constructions". *"There" is where "It" lives*.